# How to create customization theme in opencart

Tags: opencart

I have developed one ecommerce website in opencart with its inbuilt functions but now I am trying to display any four products on home page and I am not able to do that. I am trying to create function in opencart but my function is throwing server error.

Please anyone give me solution.

Comment: Update the question with your new function and error. Also your question title and description doesn't seem to match !

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in "Featured" module (Extensions >> Modules >> Featured) to display any intended numbers of products on Home page (or any other pages).

Don't try to make any changes before you are familiar enough with the core code of opencart.